# Where can I see the differents "Hibernate Console Configurations" in Eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I am creating different Hibernate Console Configurations in order to execute a reverse engineering process whit Eclipse IDE. This is due to the fact that when I create a single Hibernate Console Configuration, i dont' find the way to edit this same element to modify its properties (user, password, ...) and try it again. So I must to create other and other,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found it!

I must change to Hibernate Perspective (Window -> Open Perspective -> Hibernate) and show Hibernate Configuration View (Window -> Show View -> Hibernate Configurations) from there.